# Python: writelines() called for a second time returns empty

Tags: python

Inside a python script, I use the `difflib.unified_diff()` function to receive the differences of two files. Then, following this [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#a-command-line-interface-to-difflib), I call the [writelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)() function to write the result on the screen:

```
diff = difflib.unified_diff( .... )
sys.stdout.writelines(diff)
```

Then, I also want to write the differences in a file, but I receive an empty file. Here comes the strange part: if I exchange the order of the two writelines() calls, I get a correct file but empty screen output. The same problem can also be reproduced by just calling the last command twice, like this:

```
diff = difflib.unified_diff( .... )
sys.stdout.writelines(diff)
sys.stdout.writelines(diff)
```

This will print the diff only once.

I suppose that the second time the function continues from the same (i.e. last) "line" of diff and doesn't have anything to write. So, there must be some kind of iterator I have to reset, but I couldn't find what and how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`difflib.unified_diff()` returns a *generator*. It only produces the output *once* when iterated.

If you need to write it out twice, capture the lines in a list first:

```
diff = list(difflib.unified_diff( .... ))
sys.stdout.writelines(diff)
sys.stdout.writelines(diff)
```

From the [`difflib.unified_diff()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.unified_diff):

> Compare *a* and *b* (lists of strings); return a delta (**a [*generator*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator) generating the delta lines**) in unified diff format.

*Bold emphasis mine*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the instant answer! It worked! :-D

Answer (score 1):

You have consumed the generator after the first write that `unified_diff` returns.

**difflib.unified_diff(a, b[, fromfile][, tofile][, fromfiledate][, tofiledate][, n][, lineterm])**

> Compare a and b (lists of strings); return a delta (a **generator** generating the delta lines) in unified diff format.

You need to store the output in  a list if you want to use it twice.

```
diff = list(difflib.unified_diff( .... ))
```

Once you iterate over a generator once, it has been consumed so there is nothing to iterate over the second time:

```
In [13]: gen = (i for i in (1,2,3))    
In [14]: for i in gen:
           print(i)
   ....:     
1
2
3   
In [15]: for i in gen: # already been consumed
           print(i)
   ....:
```

Calling list on  the gen means you store all the lines in a list so you can iterate and use the lines as many times as you need:

```
In [19]: gen = (i for i in (1,2,3))    
In [20]: l = list(gen)    
In [21]: for i in l:
           print(i)
   ....:     
1
2
3    
In [22]: for i in l:
             print(i)
   ....:     
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thank you both for the quick answer! You both provided the same solution, though I can only mark one of them as THE solution. :-)

Comment: @MakisH, no worries, Martijn needs the rep ;)